# Why does the WinAPI function ::NetUserGetLocalGroups() not return all groups?

Tags: windows, winapi, usergroups

I have a user `DOMAIN\User.Name` that is according to `whoami /GROUPS` in somewhat over 200 windows domain groups.

When I try do determine all groups for this user using the WinAPI function ::NetUserGetLocalGroups() I get only 27 groups for said user:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <lm.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  //query the domain server for the groups of the user
  LPGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 pBuf = NULL;
  DWORD dwLevel = 0;
  DWORD dwPrefMaxLen = MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH;
  DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
  DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0;
  NET_API_STATUS nStatus = MAX_NERR;

  std::wstring serverName(L"\\\\MyDomainNameDns");
  std::wstring userName(L"DOMAIN\\user.name");

  nStatus = ::NetUserGetLocalGroups(serverName.c_str(),
    userName.c_str(),
    dwLevel,
    LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT,
    reinterpret_cast<PBYTE*>(&pBuf),
    dwPrefMaxLen,
    &dwEntriesRead,
    &dwTotalEntries);
}
```

`dwTotalEntries` is 27 and `nStatus` is 0, so it's not that I fetch only a part of all groups. Also I tried using `::NetUserGetGroups()` instead but had no success either.

NOTE: Using .NET functionality `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups` indeed does give me all groups.

What could be the reason NetUserGetLocalGroups does not return get all groups as `whoami` or `.NET / WindowsIdentity`? What could be the difference between the groups returned/not returned?

Comment: *whoami /GROUPS* return groups from token.

Comment: @RbMm What token? Can I obtain one (e.g. for the logged in user) and obtain the groups using using that token via the WinAPI?

Comment: of course yes. process token. in what problem call `OpenProcessToken` and then `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenGroups` ?

Comment: @RbMm I was able to obtain a process token with `::OpenProcessToken`, get token Information with `::GetTokenInformation` and iterate over the group SIDs looking up the name using `::LookupAccountSid`. Thanks so far. I still don't understand though why I see some groups only having the token, while I do see only part of them when not obtaining a token and using `::NetUserGetLocalGroups`

Comment: this is different functions. with `GetTokenInformation` you look what is actually asigned for current user token. with `NetUserGetLocalGroups` you look in persistent  sam database. question - what you actually need ?

Comment: Maybe I get the question wrong, but, isn't that the point of "NetUserGetLocalGroups", returning only _local groups_, _not_ domain groups? Aren't you're extra 173 groups or so, domain groups?

Comment: @Christian.K The result of `NetUserGetLocalGroups` contains also domain groups. That is what confused me. I found a windows user group discussion that clarifies what is going on. See my answer below.
@RbMm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some more digging I found the following statement in [a windows user group discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/qKHgFgQVMu4/L91KI5bdulIJ):

> Actually, NetUserGetLocalGroups / NetUserGetGroups
> do *not* handle nested or universal groups in windows 2000
> native domains.  Enumerating the SIDs from the token is
> the only reliable way.

So, in other words, use `::NetUserGetLocalGroups` / `NetUserGetGroups` if you want *direct* group membership. If you want to know the group ownership in order to find out whether a user has the right to do something, use the token / SID way (e.g. using `::OpenProcessToken`, `::GetTokenInformation` and `::LookupAccountSid`).

### Example

A user is in the (domain local) group `Employee`. All employees have keycard access to the building, so the `Employee` group is am member of the `HasBuildingAccess` (domain local) group.

If you want to know, whether a user is (directly) in the `Employee` group, use `::NetUserGetLocalGroups`. It contains the `Employee` group, but not the `HasBuildingAccess` group.

If you want to know however, whether a user has the right to access the building, enumerate the SIDs from the token. It will contain the `HasBuildingAccess` group.